# Get grouped information by week or month

Tags: elasticsearch

We're storing our documents in a collection `coll1` is storing documents like:

```
{
    "user" : "user1",
    "timestamp" : "2017-01-11T13:57:39.405Z",
    "matter" : "matter"
}

{
    "user" : "user1",
    "timestamp" : "2017-01-19T13:57:39.405Z",
    "matter" : "matter"
}

{
    "user" : "user1",
    "timestamp" : "2017-01-20T13:57:39.405Z",
    "matter" : "matter"
}

{
    "user" : "user2",
    "timestamp" : "2017-01-11T13:57:39.405Z",
    "matter" : "matter"
}

{
    "user" : "user2",
    "timestamp" : "2017-01-11T13:57:39.405Z",
    "matter" : "matter"
}
```

We need to get information like:

```
user - number of documents in `coll1` --> grouped by weeks or months
```

Desired results example:

```
"user1" - week 1 - 1
"user1" - week 2 - 2
"user2" - week 1 - 2
```

I've no idea how to get it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this, i.e. first aggregate on the users and then for each user aggregate on the week of year. For each weekly bucket, you'll get the number of matching documents in the `doc_count` field.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "users": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "weeks": {
          "terms": {
            "script": {
              "inline": "doc.timestamp.date.getWeekOfWeekyear()"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that you need to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/modules-scripting-security.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) in order for this to work.

Comment: @Jordi care to give some feedback?

Comment: Sorry @Val for not providing any feedback up to now. Is there anyway to enable `inline dynamic scripting` using `curl` and then disable it?

Comment: Nope, dynamic scripting can only be enabled via the configuration and restarting the server... it would be too easy for attackers otherwise

Comment: According to [this documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-painless.html) I would be able to use `painless` in inline by default... Would I need to change something in your snippet in order to use `painless` instead if `groovy`?